# Dependency injection, infer object values - typescript

Tags: typescript

Link to playground:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/MYewdgzgLgBAjjAvDA3gWAFA2-ArgUwCcBPAeQCMArALlUxxgDMwBGWgCgEokA+GABUIgAtgEsI+AHSF8EEABsAbvnYtOAGno5mAJg4BDQgHNaYXMPJFuiPoaMwA1DADMmrNrDODx0+cuFrW2NHGBY3bABfTCiMTFBIWDgCEgAxMCQYAB4AaRh8AA8ofDAAEwgYfTBiHnY4WmzAiohiMGAsgBU8wuKymABrfGIQRhgoYgAHfGH4Gv1x0Vp2xvR3eOhUJjB1TZ1t5mcYCIy4AG050QBdLTXYGQhx8AkM-QB3fVFYZi5rx9gS-FA-xKGV07DuD0g+E4WhkUFwhHS+3Y-0B+BK0IwMTivxgd2OyWIaVqnHYAHIkkQyFRSRjMAB6Om42QwEogWRgUmwIyiZQwYT4Ji4eTyUblCC4cYPQiwTCYIA

---

I've been sitting with this for a while now and I've been trying to draw some inspiration from previous answers with no luck

I basically have the an object like this:

```
const query = {
  fn: () => Promise<any>,
  fn2: (arg: T) => T
  fn3: (arg: T) => T + 2
}
```

and then I'm running it in a function where i extract all of the methods and run them sequentially:

```
// import * as queries

const seqFn = <T keyof typeof queries>(query: T) => {
  const { fn, fn2, fn3 } = queries[api]
  const res = await fn()
  const res2 = fn2(res)
  return fn3(res2)
}
```

which works nicely as ts is capable of inferring the types going in and out of every function, which means i also get type safety for the return function of seqFn.

However, now I would like to extract the import and make it dependency injected instead:

```
const seqFn = (queries) => <T keyof typeof queries>(query: T) => {
  const { fn, fn2, fn3 } = queries[api]
  const res = await fn()
  const res2 = fn2(res)
  return fn3(res2)
}
```

and this is where i run into problems. I would like to keep the same behaviour as above with the inference but no matter how i type it I only manage to get the keys inferred, not the functions themselves. I've tried different variants but I always end up in something like this:

```
type queryTypes<K extends querymain> = {
  [key in keyof K]: {
    fn: K[key]['fn']
    decoder: K[key]['fn2']
    transformationFn: K[key]['fn3']
  }
}

type inferQueryTypes<T extends querymain> = T extends queryTypes<T>
  ? queryTypes<T>
  : never

export const queryFnn =
  <K extends querymain>(queries: inferQueryTypes<K>) =>
  async <T extends keyof inferQueryTypes<K>>(api: T) => {
    const { fn, fn2, fn3 } = queries[api]
    const response = await fn()
    const decoded = fn2(response)
    return fn3(decoded)
  }
```

I'm obviously doing something wrong but what exactly? Could somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please provide a minimum reproducable example. One which can be copy and pasted in a TypeScript editor like the [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) so we don't have to spend time trying to fix unrelated problems before getting to the problem of the question.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/MYewdgzgLgBAjjAvDA3gWAFA2-ArgUwCcBPAeQCMArALlUxxgDMwBGWgCgEokA+GABUIgAtgEsI+AHSF8EEABsAbvnYtOAGno5mAJg4BDQgHNaYXMPJFuiPoaMwA1DADMmrNrDODx0+cuFrW2NHGBY3bABfTCiMTFBIWDgCEgAxMCQYAB4AaRh8AA8ofDAAEwgYfTBiHnY4WmzAiohiMGAsgBU8wuKymABrfGIQRhgoYgAHfGH4Gv1x0Vp2xvR3eOhUJjB1TZ1t5mcYCIy4AG050QBdLTXYGQhx8AkM-QB3fVFYZi5rx9gS-FA-xKGV07DuD0g+E4WhkUFwhHS+3Y-0B+BK0IwMTivxgd2OyWIaVqnHYAHIkkQyFRSRjMAB6Om42QwEogWRgUmwIyiZQwYT4Ji4eTyUblCC4cYPQiwTCYIA

Comment: would [this](https://tsplay.dev/mArjZW) answer your question? I had to make some assumptions about your code. For example that the functions are always called `fn1`, `fn2` and `fn3` and that the function always returns the result of `fn3`. If that meets your needs, I would write an answer.

Comment: ahh ok, i thought we could make it infer even deeper but i guess it would work actually

Comment: we can make it an answer. i'm still curious if there is a way without explicitly specifying the return type?

Comment: as far as TypeScript is concerned, the type of `fn3` is just `(...args: any[]) => any`. If we leave out the explicit return type, It would be just `Promise<any>`. At some point, the TypeScript devs decided that in such cases, TypeScript would give derived variables a concrete type. They could have also typed `fn3` something like `K[T]["fn3"]` but decided to do an eager evaluation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function needs a generic constraint so that the general shape of `K` is known. This allows us to do `K[T]["fn3"]` for the return type of the function.

```
type ValidateQueries<T extends Record<string, {
    fn1: () => Promise<any>
    fn2: (...args: any[]) => any
    fn3: (...args: any[]) => any
}>> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] & {
    fn1: () => Promise<any>
    fn2: (arg: Awaited<ReturnType<T[K]["fn1"]>>) => any
    fn3: (args: ReturnType<T[K]["fn2"]>) => any
  }
}

const queryFn = <
  K extends Record<string, {
    fn1: () => Promise<any>
    fn2: (...args: any[]) => any
    fn3: (...args: any[]) => any
  }>
>(q: ValidateQueries<K>) => async <T extends keyof K>(api: T): Promise<ReturnType<K[T]["fn3"]>> => {
  const { fn1, fn2, fn3 } = q[api]
  const response = await fn1()
  const decoded = fn2(response)
  return fn3(decoded)
}
```

We need the explicit return type because the compiler eagerly determines a *"wrong"* or too general type for `fn3`. Auto-inference would therefore lead to a return type of `Promise<any>`.

```
const res = queryFn(q)('queryObj')

queryFn({
  queryObj: {
    fn1: () => Promise.resolve(1),
    fn2: (arg: string) => arg + 3, // Error
    fn3: (arg: number) => arg + 1,
  }
})('queryObj')
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/MYewdgzgLgBAjjAvDA3gWAFA2-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-f6A7PYhKiUGcWiIiYokWU6lJLNbYFSzwyx58Z7YFXQVDHMKY3rc6NIeBbfR1nZaEewGQQBLgCSz-SE4njrjLzewTKmk+ZWe6dhrjeQfCcLQycmU47Odgn0Bn+93JUYFcwNezuqRBamA8acOwADkQEkBQlAQV+mDQSB7BDngwGwbQqELHaCLjMi0iyAoyiqBoXLuryPgwJ0nxGDcwROK4MAAPRMTAACihBCIQZE8tilFmBYVhyvRoThNG0TgVBGqwfBP5AA)

Comment: Important to note that now the return type of fn1 and fn2 can be mismatched since you call fn2 with the return value of fn1, and likewise fn3 with the return value of fn2.

Comment: thank you for your answer. as caTS mentioned tho, there could be a type mismatch. for example i would like to use a function `identity` to sometimes instead of actually specifying a fn3 function. the signature of it would be `(arg: T) => T` but typescript gives `unknown`. but if there really is no other way then that's the way it is :/

Comment: @Martin - See my update. We can add a validation type which checks that each fn must have the arg type of the previous return type.

Comment: But this won't affect the implementation of the function. Only how it can be called.

Comment: thank you @TobiasS!
i have one question. why is this part needed? what does that mean besides "this intersection that":

`T[K] &`

Comment: @Martin - you can see this as some kind of inference "hack". Without the intersection, `T` can not be inferred at all and stays `unknown`. With the intersection, the compiler knows that whatever is in this object will be inferred as `T[K]` but must still adhere to the constraints on the other side of the intersection.